# Extract a 1D array from 2D array: a Python program (numpy) to extract each column as a separate 1D array and use. I want to extract 1d arrays

Tags: python

Say I have a 2d array; T = [[11, 12, 5, 2], [15, 6,1, 0], [10, 8, 12, 5], [12,15,8,6]]
I want to write a Python code to extract the columns of a 2D array and save to 1D arrays. I read the integer data from a csv file. The data is preferably integer.

```
for r in T;
    for c in r:
        A[r]= ....
        print()
```

I want the output as
A = [11, 15, 10, 12]

etc. All 4 columns are to be extracted to 4 1D arrays.

Comment: If `T` is [tag:numpy] array you can do `A = T[:, 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described is just the transpose.

You can achieve this with numpy like this:

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = [[11, 12, 5, 2], [15, 6,1, 0], [10, 8, 12, 5], [12,15,8,6]]
my_array = np.array(my_array)
transposed = my_array.T


print(transposed)
```

The result would be this:

```
[[11 15 10 12]
 [12  6  8 15]
 [ 5  1 12  8]
 [ 2  0  5  6]]
```

you could also get any (single) row you wanted like this:

```
print(transposed[0])
print(transposed[1])
...
```

which would give this:

```
[11 15 10 12]
[12  6  8 15]
...
```

Comment: @prasadji, you are welcome,  if it helped, please tick the box and upvote as it also helps others...

Comment: Well I did that. I got the following pop up: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded"..          So let me know if I have to do further something to get reputation. I am totally new to this forum and have no idea about these terminologies and procedures. If you have any idea let me know. Thank you once again for helping me.

Comment: You might not be able to vote until sufficient feedback, But i believe that you can accept the question as the correct answer (with the grey tick that turns into a green tick).